# How to store the value of a translation via angular translate in a global variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been trying to solve this problem for some time now. Couldn't really find a feasible solution.

My objective : I am trying to assign the value of an angular translation (done using $translate) to a global variable so that I can use it later for dynamic variable value assignment. The translations are contained in a json file and configured in angular.module(..).config(..)

My js file :

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl',
    function ($translate, $scope) {
        var temp_text='';
        $translate(['Text1']).then(function (translations) {
            temp_text=translations.Text1;
            alert(temp_text);
        });
        alert(temp_text);

});
```

The problem is that the temp_text value is blank for the first pop up and the proper value for the second pop up.

How can I save the value of the translation in the global variable for future use?

Answer (score 2):

you can use $rootScope for storing a variable or data that is common to all controllers in your app, is the most convenient way.

your controller should be like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl',
function ($translate, $scope,$rootScope) {
    var temp_text='';
    $translate(['Text1']).then(function (translations) {
        temp_text=translations.Text1;
        $rootScope.myGlobalVariable=temp_text;
    });
```

});

this a [working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/4IXR0510DDJ2qvDljT8S?p=preview)

Comment: Same issue with this fix. When I tried to log the value of $rootScope.myGlobalVariable after the $translate snippet, there was 'undefined' instead of any valid value.

Comment: @ geek_c ok I am trying to make a demo

Comment: you may need to use locastorage dependency instead of rootscope where you can get it by getItem() method after Refresh too

Comment: Thanks @aitnasser for the working solution. It did not exactly provide a solution to my problem, however I tinkered with your code a bit and managed to find out that instead of using a promise to translate the text, I could use $translate.instant() directive to get and store the translated value in  temporary variable. For example

`var temp=$translate.instant('text1');
alert(temp);`